# Sum like values in Multi-Dimensional array php

Tags: php

I need to sum the values in element 1 of my array where the values in element 0 are duplicate.

**Here's a small piece of my array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 128
)
Array
(
    [0] => 39
    [1] => 4
)
```

**The results i'm expecting to see**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 131
)
Array
(
    [0] => 39
    [1] => 4
)
```

I'm still really new to PHP so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does `Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
)` come from? How is this expected? From your question I can only expect the first two outputs.

Comment: Sorry, that shouldn't have been included. I've update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of array_intersect, array_column and array_sum to only iterate twice. (One for each unique column 0 value).

```
$col0 = array_column($arr, 0);
$col1 = array_column($arr, 1);

Foreach(array_unique($col0) as $val){
   $res[] = [$val, array_sum(array_intersect_key($col1, array_intersect($col0,[$val])))];
}
Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/gKb5b

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done it is made sure all duplicates where put in the same array.

```
// Your data
$sample = [[3, 1],[3, 2],[3, 128],[39, 4]];

foreach($sample as $array){
  $tmp[$array[0]][] = $array[1];
}

# Output: {"3":[1,2,128],"39":[4]}
```

Now sum the arrays, and put it back to the structure it originally was.

```
foreach($tmp as $k => $v){
  $new[] = [$k, array_sum($v)];
}

# Output: [[3,131],[39,4]]
```

But many roads lead to Rome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It may help you.

```
$array = array(["0" => 3, "1" => 1] , ["0" => 3, "1" => 2], ["0" => 3, "1" => 128], ["0" => 39, "1" => 4]);
$finalArray = [];
foreach($array as $a) {
   $finalArray[$a[0]][0] = $a[0];
   $finalArray[$a[0]][1] = !isset($finalArray[$a[0]][1]) ? $a[1] : $finalArray[$a[0]][1] + $a[1];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($finalArray);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. I have separated into two foreach. Hope it helps.

```
    <?php

   $a = [[3,1],[3,2],[3,128],[39,4]];

   $result=[];
   $temp = [];

   foreach($a as $line) {
     $temp[$line[0]] += $line[1];
   }

   foreach($temp as $k => $value) {
      $result[]=[$k ,$value];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [ [ 3, 1],[  3, 2 ],[  3, 128], [ 39, 4]];
$sum = [];
foreach($arr as $value) {
   $sum[$value[0]][] = $value[1];
}
foreach($sum as $key=>$value ) {
  $result[] = [ $key, array_sum($value)];
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 131
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39
            [1] => 4
        )
)
```

Comment: This is pretty much a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50628833/3392762

Comment: Yes but your logic is in only one line. That's great.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data =
[
    [3,1],
    [3,2],
    [3,128],
    [39,4]
];

foreach($data as $item)
    $sums[$item[0]] = ($sums[$item[0]] ?? 0) + $item[1];

$result = array_map(null, array_keys($sums), $sums);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 131,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 39,
    1 => 4,
  ),
)
```